# The problem with cognitive Service to Identify. I can't write the query correctly

Tags: python, azure-cognitive-services

What should I write in the body? And how do I get the name of my person in the personal group in return?

```
import http.client, urllib, base64, json, requests

headers = {
    # Request headers
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',  # this should be the content type
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx',
}

params = {
    # Request parameters
    "personGroupId": "nikitasyomkin",
    "faceIds": [
        "6564e492-a09c-4bab-906b-50507bcc9351",
        "2dea2b5b-5992-4350-b911-365e6bc06355",
        "5f360bd7-b3ed-4840-866f-3f5777e95639"
    ],
    "maxNumOfCandidatesReturned": 1,
    "confidenceThreshold": 0.5
}

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('XXXXXX.cognitiveservices.azure.com')
conn.request("POST", "/face/v1.0/identify?%s" % params, "body", headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
data = response.read()
print(data)
conn.close()
```

Comment: Figured out what to shove in the body. In response I receive:
[{"personId":"2ab9856e-1574-473f-aa06-398399b48a09","confidence":0.50224}]}
How do I get a person's name from this query?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [official API reference](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395239) , you can not get person's name from Identify API.
If you want to get a person's name via persionID you get , you can call [this API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039523f) :

```
GET  https://XXXXXX.cognitiveservices.azure.com/face/v1.0/persongroups/<personGroupId>/persons/<persionId>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @MarkXado, how's going ? Has your issue be solved now ? Pls let me know if you need any assistance